# Деление блока MDL

Tags: html, css, material-design

Изначально было так:

[image]

Хотя в "контенте" сделать два блока, я дабавил ещё один (8)

[image]

Блок (4) съехал в низ. Но так да, сетка 12 (8 и 4 съехали в низ) все нормально, т.к добавив 8 я создал новую сетку.

Как мне поделить блок 8 на 2 части? Вот так:
[image]

Примечания: Вариант с созданием новой сетки, типа:

**Старая сетка: 8 и 4**
**Новая сетка: 8**

### Не подходит. Нужно только использовать 1 сетку, в которой 1-й блок (8) нужно поделить.

```html
<main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
  <div class="mdl-grid ali-content">
    <div class="ali-graphs mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-color--white mdl-color-text--grey-500 mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col">............</div>
    <div class="ali-cards mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing">
      <div class="ali-updates mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
        <div class="mdl-card__title">.......</div>
        <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">........</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ali-separator mdl-cell--1-col"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: покажите ваш код пожалуйста?

Comment: @ДенисПавлик чтобы дополнять вопрос, используйте кнопку [edit]. )